# XML Schema: mandating timezone on xsd:date

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Is it at all possible, when defining an XML schema, to mandate that an element of type `xsd:date` must contain timezone information?

I was reading the XML Schema specification for `xsd:date`, and it seems to me that there's no way to actually guarantee this without resorting to use regular expressions, which I certainly don't want to do.

Am I missing something, or am I doomed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, regular expressions are the usual answer (and probably the only one).

In XSD 1.1, you can and should use the [explicitTimezone](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-explicitTimezone) facet to derive a restriction of `date` that requires timezone information.